# Get multiple routes from some points

Tags: qgis, shapefile, route

I'm working on a layer of points with QGIS, and what I want is to create some routes/paths following some of these points.
[image: Some points on my layer]

The attribute table looks like this

[image: Attribute table looks]

What I want is per example, create a route following this pattern [A7, A10, A11, B1], and another route [A9, A8, A7, A10, A11, A12]

Comment: You had a tag for Python but did not mention using that or include a code snippet so I've removed it.

Comment: The patterns you mentioned seem random to me unless you have another field to describe them. I think you can create a new field with predefined values to describe the intended order for each path and use the points to path tool from processing toolbox.

Comment: You may find the ["Points to path"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#points-to-path) tool relevant to you, but again as was mentioned by @Esmaeel you will need some extra details for e.g. the *'Order expression'* or the *'Path group expression'*, better both